# The specified deps.json [] does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Asp.net Core with EntityFramework.Core. I'm having troubleshot migrations and Scaffold after format my pc.

when I write these in Package Manager Console

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\SQL2017DEV;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Db

Add-Migration Initial

error is 
"The specified deps.json [D:\TFS\Erdi\Erdi\AspCoreWeb.Site\AspCoreWeb.Site.deps.json] does not exist"

[MyProjectFolder]\AspCoreWeb.Site.deps.json

I think it try to find my debug folder.

This solutioun is working other computers

I'm repair my visual studio but it hasn't changed

Comment: To check whether it is specific to this project, create a new .net core project and run this command. Have you set the Default project in the PMC window? Try to restore your project before run command.

Comment: yes it's my default project in PMC window. and it was happend all solutions in my pc

Answer (score 13):

In my case; was fixed by changing the `Startup Project` (via Solution Properties) to the project that has EF Context file.

Comment: This was indeed my issue in 2021 with .net 5 really we have to do this crazy

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks

Comment: but what if my context is in a class library (non-executable)?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the Startup Project is where the connection string is and select the project in the `Default project` of `Package Manager Console` where the db context is at.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with migration in VS2019. I have been facing a similar issue and was getting below error:

```
The specified deps.json [YourProjectLocation]\ProjectName.deps.json doesn't exists.
```

When I used dotnet CLI for migrations and it worked and was able to generate migration and update the same using dotnet CLI.

dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Package Manager Console to "Add-Migration" or "Update-Database", be sure that the project where you want the migration is selected as the Startup project in Visual Studio and this project is also the default in Package Manager Console.

Solution Explorer:

[image]

Package Manager Console:
[image]

If you are using the dotnet CLI, then you have to navigate to the right project folder and run the migration commands from there.

Answer (score 1):

this problem generally occurs because of path issues. You should change your "outputPath" in the "project.assets.json" file.

```
D:\TFS\Erdi\Erdi\AspCoreWeb.Site\AspCoreWeb.Site.deps.json]  instead of this, 

D:\TFS\Erdi\Erdi\AspCoreWeb.Site\obj\AspCoreWeb.Site.deps.json]
```

i think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Just run into this problem and this comment led me to notice that I'm seeing `Debug` in the path when I an building in `Release` configuration.

Comment: The solution in this case was add `--configuration Release` to the `dotnet ef` command.

Answer (score -2):

Just Go to VS 2022
It Worked for me

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. Consider to delete your answer and post this a comment on the question instead. You should at least explain your answer and try to point out why you think this should be an answer.

Answer (score -3):

go to bin folder and copy files in it include deps.json to the path that see in error.

Comment: That is not a valid for this error. You can't manually copy these files every time.